# wired network problem

Tags: 16.04, networking, wired

I use 16.04, and LAN connection, initially LAN was working fine, but since last month it is not connecting automatically.what should I do ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Include the contents of the following commands.  Copy and paste the output into your question as an edit.  `ifconfig -a` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nmcli dev show`? Thanks.

Comment: While editing my own post (updating outputs of asked commands) there is a problem it is showing "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links." Help me!!